# what type of request is this in nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I am receiving a request from a hardware device, I don't know the request type.

```
110.224.13.92 - - [09/Nov/2017:06:22:08 +0000] "170215718,15,1_35T02B0164M_27,35.154.97.178,8080,airtelgprs.com,T1:10 S,T2:1 M,Ad1:1234567890,Ad2:0000000000,TOF:19800 S,,OSC:60 KM,OST:30 S,GPS:NO,Ignition:OFF,*1A" 400 173 "-" "-"
```

This is the nginx access log. I want to accept this request and access the data in my ruby on rails backend.
How to access it under ruby on rails controller?

Comment: Nginx doesn’t know either. It’s not a http request and nginx is (basically) http-server.

Comment: There is a module for proxy tcp streams

Comment: @Alexey in the stream config i have to specify proxy_pass, how to pass this to ruby on rails backend?